# Is there a wildcard for === in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that tests a few things, like this:

```
function myfunc(user, foo, bar){
   if(user.foo === foo && user.bar === bar){
    //add some data to an array
   }
}
```

In some exceptions I don't care what either foo or bar is. How can I make them always true when calling the function. I'm fine with changing the inner workings of the function, as long as it't not to bad for performance.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You want `===` to do something other than testing for equality? You want to change `===` to always result in `true`? Nonsense.

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run. @ Kristoffer: When asking for help, *stick around* for a few minutes so you can clarify the question in response to comments, answers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that's often used is

```
function myfunc(user, foo, bar){
   if((foo===undefined || user.foo === foo) &&
      (bar===undefined || user.bar === bar)) {
    //add some data to an array
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything about `undefined` in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: often `undefined` is used as wildcard value... it's also what you get when not passing a parameter or not setting an object field.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder presumably, you would pass in `null` or omit the value altogether (which would be undefined) in those cases where you don't care about that particular value.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: Maybe. The question makes little sense. I wouldn't make that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to check if `foo` and `bar` match a `skip` value:

```
var ALWAYS_VALID_FOO = {},
    ALWAYS_VALID_BAR = {};

function myfunc(user, foo, bar) {
  if ((user.foo === foo || foo === ALWAYS_VALID_FOO) &&
      (user.bar === bar || bar === ALWAYS_VALID_BAR)) {
    // Do work here
  }
}
```

`ALWAYS_VALID_*` can be `undefined` or `null` if these will never be valid values for `foo` or `bar`.  Alternatively, you can check the length of the provided arguments:

```
var fooProvided = arguments.length >= 2, barProvided = arguments.length >= 3;
```

and switch in the same way as above.